# Running Server Essential 2012 along server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain, windows-server-2012, essentials-2012, windows-server-essentials

i want to install server 2012 on a new machine which will run side by side with my windows small business server 2003. When i install it however i get the choice of clean install or migration. I do not want to migrate i just want to run it side-by-side as the server 2012 machine will be used for SVN. My confusion is when the clean install prompt comes up for what i want to call the internal domain name, i cannot let it join the existing domain name. If i give it a new domain name will it simply run side by side on the server or is it going to ruin all my existing network setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have two SBS/Essentials servers on the same domain. [This is a published and documented limitation of the product.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc672103%28WS.10%29.aspx) There is a 7 day migration period that can be extended twice. The longest that they can co-exist is 21 days for migration, after that, a built-in mechanism causes them to start rebooting.

You're going to need a full server OS.

Comment: So if i used the full server os i can continue to run the old sbs 2003 on the same domain as the full server os?

Comment: Yes. Keep in mind that Server 2003 is going end of extended support in about two years. It's getting toward that time when you should start planning a migration off of it.

Comment: Well we are expanding the business in size so it would probably make sense to get the server 2012 and start slowly migrating. Thanks for your help